# recompiling to avoid crashing R session

Tags: stan, rstan

How to avoid recompiling?

My `stan()` is recompiling to avoid crashing R session.

To validate my model, I want to replicate various models for many data from known distributions. However `rstan::stan()` always recompile my stan file, so it took a very long time. How to avoid recompiling.

**Edit for comment-------------**

Memorandum for conversion from `rstan::stan()` to `rstan::sampling()`.

In `rstan::stan`, its variable name is `model_name`

```
 m <- "foo.stan"
 rstan::stan( model_name =m, data =...)
```

On the other hand, in `rstan::sampling` its variable name is `object`

```
   m <- "foo.stan"
   m <- stan_model(m)
   rstan::sampling( object = m , data = ...)
```

Please be careful !! The variable name is different !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function `stan_model` to compile, then use the compiled model output in the `sampling` function.  For example:

```
m <- stan_model('foo.stan')
fit <- sampling(m, data = ...)
```

instead of

```
fit <- stan('foo.stan', data = ...)
```

Comment: Yes, the first, `model_name`, takes a path to a file containing the program as text.  The second, `stan_model`, takes a compiled model, like the one you get from `stan_model()`.

Comment: I have tried, but the above error occurs. What does this error mean ?

Comment: For the `rstan::sampling` call, you want to pass it the compiled model produced by `stan_model()`.